# Image of the upper half complex plane, under the function $g(z) = e^{2\pi i z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** Given $W = \{z: z=x+iy, \ y>0\}$ and $g(z) = e^{2 \pi i z},$ what does the set $g(W)$ look like, and is it simply connected?

**Attempt:** $W$ represents the upper-half complex plane. And $$g(z) = e^{2 \pi i (x+iy)} = \cdots = e^{-2\pi y}(\cos (2 \pi x) + i \sin (2 \pi x)).$$ (Am I on the right track?)

I know simply connected means that there are no holes in the set, but I don't know how to describe the set geometrically.

**Further attempt:** Since $e^{2 \pi i z} = e^{-2 \pi y}(e^{2 \pi i x})$ then $|e^{2 \pi i z}| = |e^{-2 \pi y}|$ and $y>0 \implies |e^{-2 \pi y}| \in (0,1).$ So $|e^{2 \pi i z}| \in (0, e^{2 \pi i x}).$

Right?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. You may simplify the question a bit by considering $g$ as the composition of two maps $v \circ u$, where $u(x) = 2i \pi x$, and $v(y) = \exp y$; then you may easily determine $u(W)$, and then in turn, $v(u(W))$.

Comment: @Circonflexe I am a bit confused.. how does $g = v \circ u,$ when $g$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ and $u,v$ are functions of $x,y$ only?

Comment: Not the same name for the variables, sorry, but you should be able to fix this.

Comment: @Circonflexe I have updated my attempts above - can you please clarify further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your first attempt very well, and your “Further attempt” rather less well, unless by “$(0,e^{2\pi ix})$” you mean the open straight-line segment from the origin to the point $(\cos x, i\sin x)$ on the unit circle. I think that what you already have should be enough to answer your questions, as long as you ask yourself whether there are any missing points in the image-set (“range”).

Comment: Ok. So can I say the following: the argument of $e^{2\pi iz}$ is $2\pi x$, and the point $\cos2\pi x+i\sin 2\pi x$ is on the unit circle, at exactly $2\pi x$ angle (from the right wing of $x$-axis).

Now $x \in \mathbb{R}$, hence the argument (the angle closed with the right wing of $x$-axis) is going from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, thus describing the whole circle. And the radius of the circle varies from $0$ to $1$. So, it's a disk around the origin, without the origin itself. So we have a hole, and the region is not simply connected?

Comment: Perfectly correct: the image is the punctured disk, not simply connected.